# trying to run jsdoc and import it to documentation

Tags: node.js, jsdoc

hello I'm trying to run this script:

> index.js

```
/**
 * My typedef for each object.
 * @typedef {Object} MyObject1
 * @property {String} username Your username
 * @property {String} realname Your real name.
 * @property {boolean} isUnique Are you unique as a person?
 */
module.exports = {
    /**
     * Person One!
     * @type {MyObject1}
     */
    myperson: {
      username: 'TheDragonSlayer',
      realname: 'George',
      isUnique: true
    },
    /**
     * Person Two!
     * @type {MyObject1}
     */
    myperson2: {
      username: 'BobMagee',
      realname: 'Bob',
      isUnique: false
    }
  }
```

> tutor.js

```
    const persons = require('./index.js');

/**
 * @typedef {import ('./index.js').MyObject1} MyObject1
 */

class test {
  constructor(options = {}) {
    /**
     * The person for this file.
     * @type {MyObject1}
     */
    this.person = options.person ? persons[options.person] : persons.myperson2;
  }
}

module.exports = test;
```

i found this script on google. I just want to know why on my computer it can't run and import it into the documentation. i have try another script too and the result still same